# Initialize a bean both from Spring and Guice

Tags: java, spring, guice

I have a little bit strange situation about integrating Spring and Guice. Our current project is working with Guice flawlessly. However, we need to extend it via giving dependency to an external Spring project. But that means we need to create the beans of that project in spring context. Here's the tricky part: we also need to use some of our existing guice bindings in spring beans. I can not simply move those guice injected classes to become spring beans, and I don't want to duplicate them.

The question is: is it possible to initialize a class with both spring and guice, and able to inject wherever I want? I'm aware of [spring-guice](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-guice), but is it the right API to use? Are there any other options, preferable internal (such as using javax.inject.Inject annotation) - or is this integration completely a bullshit and we should never mix Spring and Guice no matter what?

Thanks,

Tugcem.